# Expression tree to know if a date is between 2 dates in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression, func

I need to build a "between" function to check if a date is included in a range of 2 dates. I wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
private static Expression<Func<TElement, bool>> IsDateBetween<TElement>(Expression<Func<TElement, object>> valueSelector, DateTime date)
{
    var p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();

    var after = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(
        Expression.Property(valueSelector.Body, "FromDate"), Expression.Constant(date.Date, typeof(DateTime)));

    var before = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
        Expression.Property(valueSelector.Body, "ToDate"), Expression.Constant(date.Date, typeof(DateTime)));

    Expression body = Expression.And(after, before);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
}
```

I call it in this way:

```
DataContext.EventHistories.Where(IsDateBetween<EventHistory>(h => new { h.FromDate, h.ToDate }, dateInTheMiddle))
```

I must use this way because date not supported in linq entities.

Thanks

Comment: Side note - if those `DateTime` values will ever have non-midnight times, it's usually better to use a semi-open interval to model ranges (inclusive lower bound, exclusive upper) - it makes reasoning about such ranges easier (as well as avoiding having to find, e.g. the closest time that is just before a particular midnight)

Comment: It might not be what your are looking for, but there's an amazing library called Intenso Time Period Library. Theres an object called TimeRange where you can use HasInside(DateTime date) method to see if your Date is inside the period. It's so useful.. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like that

```
public static IQueryable<TElement> IsDateBetween<TElement>(this IQueryable<TElement> queryable, 
                                                           Expression<Func<TElement, DateTime>> fromDate, 
                                                           Expression<Func<TElement, DateTime>> toDate, 
                                                           DateTime date)
{
    var p = fromDate.Parameters.Single();
    Expression member = p;

    Expression fromExpression = Expression.Property(member, (fromDate.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name);
    Expression toExpression = Expression.Property(member, (toDate.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name);

    var after = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(fromExpression,
         Expression.Constant(date, typeof(DateTime)));

    var before = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(
        toExpression, Expression.Constant(date, typeof(DateTime)));

    Expression body = Expression.And(after, before);

    var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TElement, bool>>(body, p);
    return queryable.Where(predicate);
}
```

usage

```
DataContext.EventHistories.WhereDateBetween(h =>  h.FromDate, h => h.ToDate, dateInTheMiddle));
```

but it's quite complicated to do

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now();

var result = DataContext.EventHistories.Where(m => m.FromDate >= myDate && m.ToDate<=myDate );
```

**EDIT**

Well, to simulate the `DateTime.Date`, you could do :

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now.Date();
var res = histories.AsQueryable()
.Where(m => 
EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(m.FromDate.Year, m.FromDate.Month, m.FromDate.Day, 0, 0, 0) >= DateTime.Now && 
EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(m.ToDate.Year, m.ToDate.Month, m.ToDate.Day, 0, 0, 0) <= DateTime.Now)
```

Or create an interface

```
public interface IFromDateToDate
{
    DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
}
```

and an extension method

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereDatesBetween<T>(this IQueryable<T> queryable, DateTime myDate) where T : IFromDateToDate
{
    myDate = myDate.Date;
    return queryable.Where(m =>
                           EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(m.FromDate.Year, m.FromDate.Month, m.FromDate.Day, 0, 0, 0) >= myDate &&
                           EntityFunctions.CreateDateTime(m.FromDate.Year, m.FromDate.Month, m.FromDate.Day, 0, 0, 0) <= myDate);
}
```

usage :

```
DataContext.EventHistories.WhereDatesBetween(dateInTheMiddle));
```

Comment: @DarionBadlyOne : my first (even accepted) answer didn't take care of the `.Date` part. Edit should be better

Answer (score 1):

LinQ to Entities DOES support DateTime - i use it in a project and there's no problem about it:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;    
var expiredEntities = entities.Repositories.Where(repository => repository.ExpiryDate < now).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, if I follow this correct, you would really like to write:

```
from item in MyTable
where FromDate <= Item.Somedate.Date 
   && Item.Somedate.Date <= ToDate
select item
```

But, you can't because the `Date` property of DateTime isn't supported in LINQ to entities.

Similarly, you can't write:

```
from item in MyTable
where FromDate <= Item.SomeDate 
   && Item.SomeDate <= ToDate
select item
```

because, I assume, `ToDate` is set to midnight, and if `Item.SomeDate` has a time, it will be after `ToDate`, even if it's on ToDate.

If that's the case, the proper solution, which is the common practice, is to make the upper limit an *exclusive* value (i.e, the first thing that is*not* part of the set).  Hence:

```
  toDate = toDate.Date.AddDay(1);

from item in MyTable
where FromDate <= Item.SomeDate 
   && Item.SomeDate < ToDate
select item
```

Answer (score -1):

Why bother with all that magic? Why not just do this?

```
if (date >= startDate and date <= endDate) {

}
```

Comment: Right question. Because I'm using it in a Linq query and date are not supported with linq entities