# Extensions for IQueryable to filter a DateTime-Range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API and a route that is returning a set of transactions. I want to add two filter-parameters via query string, the start-date and the end-date to filter these transactions by date (a date-range).

These parameters are both optional, so I have them as nullable types.

Since this kind of filtering by date is very common in my app I want to avoid code like that:

```
if (start.HasValue) 
{
    transactions = transaction.Where(x => x.TimestampUtc >= start.Value);
}

if (end.HasValue) 
{
    transactions = transaction.Where(x => x.TimestampUtc <= end.Value);
}
```

So the idea was to create an extension-method called DateTimeRange for `IQueryable`. This method takes 3 parameters, the field (TimestampUtc in my case) for date-filtering and the start and end-date.

```
[HttpGet("transactions")]
public IActionResult GetTransactions(DateTime? start, DateTime? end) 
{
    IQueryable<Transaction> transactions = this.TransactionRepository.All
        .DateTimeRange(x => x.TimestampUtc, start, end);

    return this.Ok(transactions);
}
```

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> DateTimeRange<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime>> keySelector, DateTime? start, DateTime? end) 
{
    // what to do here to filter my set?

    return source;
}
```

I am stuck what to do in this extension-method to filter my set. It's important to me that I am working with `IQueryable` so the actual database action is done on the database and NOT in memory for performance reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Expression.Compile` may not work in EF (as it needs expression to build SQL from it)

So here is solution which should work (as it's based on expressions)

```
    public static IQueryable<TSource> DateTimeRange<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime>> keySelector, DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {
        if (!start.HasValue && !end.HasValue)
            return source;
        var parameter = keySelector.Parameters.Single();
        var key = Expression.Property(parameter, (keySelector.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name);
        Expression before = end.HasValue ?  Expression.LessThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(end, typeof(DateTime))) : null;
        Expression after = start.HasValue ? Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(key, Expression.Constant(start, typeof(DateTime))) : null;
        Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate;
        if (before == null)
        {
            predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(after, parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            if (after == null)
                predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(before, parameter);
            else
                predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(Expression.And(after, before), parameter);
        }
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
```

You can check the results [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IAYdsC)

It is based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496019/expression-tree-to-know-if-a-date-is-between-2-dates-in-c-sharp#answer-12496560)

Comment: Wow!! That works like a charm and at the same time I learned a lot how to create expressions. Everything is translated into SQL and therefore I have a huge performance-gain which I can notice using the frontend! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```cs
public static IQueryable<TSource> DateTimeRange<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime>> selector, DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
    var startNotNull = start ?? DateTime.MinValue;
    var endNotNull = end ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

    var selectStatement = selector.Compile();
        
    return source.Where(i => selectStatement(i) >= startNotNull && selectStatement(i) <= endNotNull);
}
```

### Edit

As @GuyVdN said ...

> Performance wise I don't think it is a good idea to always execute the Where statement when start, end or both are null. It would be better to adjust the Where statement or not execute it at all when these values are null.

Here's my new version fixing the optimization issues.

```cs
public static IQueryable<TSource> DateTimeRange<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, DateTime>> selector, DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
{
    var compiledSelect = selector.Compile();

    return start switch
    {
        null when end is not null => source.Where(i => compiledSelect(i) <= end),
        not null when end is null => source.Where(i => compiledSelect(i) >= start),
        not null => source.Where(i => compiledSelect(i) >= start && compiledSelect(i) <= end),
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
    };
}
```

Comment: not sure if this would work with EF (Linq2SQL)

Comment: Performance wise I don't think it is a good idea to always execute the Where statement when start, end or both are null. It would be better to adjust the Where statement or not execute it at all when these values are null.

Comment: @GuyVdN good point, I'm updating my answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I get an error. EF Core tells me that the expression can not be translated. But the answer above works like charm!